# Remove Duplicate Records except one in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table wi_indv_training with columns:

```
trn_id || ind_id || indv_source || is_deleted
```

This table has duplicate data in composite key(trn_id, ind_id). Here, I need to delete all the records except one having duplicate data in composite key. For an instance, if the table has following data:

```
trn_id || ind_id || indv_source || is_deleted
001        001       Group             0
001        002       Group             0
001        001       Individual        0
002        001       Individual        0
```

Expected Result (indv_source is not important to check):

```
trn_id || ind_id || indv_source || is_deleted
001        001       Group             0
001        002       Group             0
002        001       Individual        0
```

Comment: Your composite key (`trn_id || ind_id`) for `Individual` are different, why would that be a duplicate?

Comment: You say you need to delete all but one with a duplicate key...How do you decide which one to keep? Why, in your example, did you discard the `001   001   Individual   0` line and not `001   001   Group   0`?

Comment: You could create a new table, run a INSERT INTO SELECT DISTINCT, then delete the old table.

Comment: I've another two tables: wi_trn_org(trn_id,grp_id) and wi_indv_org(ind_id,grp_id). The individuals in wi_indv_training can be from randomly selected individuals that are sourced as individual whereas the individuals selected from group are to be sourced as group. Here, first i want to delete all duplicate records, and then the remaining data would be checked if the individuals are individual sourced or group sourced.